# How to hide a button after clicked for ever in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to hide a button when it's clicked for ever.

I tried this code:

```js
playButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But when I close and open the app, the button will re-show again .

So how can I hide the button for ever? Thank you :)

Comment: You need to store this setting so it persists between separate executions of the app. Look at storing a setting using PreferenceManager.

Comment: You need to remember the setting on the local device. Then when the view containing the button is shown, read the setting and hide the button if necessary

Comment: There is no way to hide it for ever. You can save a value that indicates that button was clicked in `sharedpreferences` or any other kind of local storage and retrieve that value when you initialize your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't technically hide it "forever" but you can do this:

First, declare this variable in your `Activity`/`Fragment`:

```
public static final String SHARED_KEY_BUTTON_HIDE = "my_button_hidden";
```

Let's say this is your button:

```
final Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Here's the `setOnClickListenr` for the `Button`:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(SHARED_KEY_BUTTON_HIDE, true);
        editor.apply();
    }
});
```

Here's the key part:

When that `Activity` start, do this in `onCreate()` after you declare the button:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
boolean hideButton = preferences.getBoolean(SHARED_KEY_BUTTON_HIDE, false);

if(hideButton) {
    myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

This will do the job.

Comment: Thank you very much, You are a hero :)